# attach immunity debugger to a background process

Tags: windows, debugging, process, background-process, cpu-usage

I have a process that is taking up 58% CPU, a process which seems a legit dell process so I want to know why it is doing so.
(possibly some virus is hijacking the process or something).

is it possible to attach immunity debugger to a background process in windows?
if not, is there any free way to debug a background process that is running on my windows machine?

Comment: for debugger no different background process or not. any good debugger must can attach to process, except protected processes (but this is also possible for some debuggers)

Comment: Immunity debugger should be a good debugger but I could not get it to debug background windows processes. I downloaded windbg however and was able to debug a background process after running it as admin

Answer (score 0):

Download windbg -> run as administrator -> file -> attach to a process

beware however, when stopping the debug it can stop the background process as well.

Comment: some debuggers  able correct detach from process without killing it )

Comment: do not stop, just detach